# Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in php

Tags: php

How can I resolve my php errors Notice: Undefined offset: 2 ?
There is my code:

```
    <?php
    $currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
    $parts['2'];
    if ($parts['2'] == "index.php") {
        ?>
    <?php } if ($parts['2'] != "index.php") { ?>
    <?php } //die("desffd");  ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is value of `$currentFile`

Comment: you are trying to access the unavailable value. i think $currentfile have only one `/` so i think you are trying to get second part of string . so use $parts['0']

Comment: @Krishna Thanks! When I change each number 2 to zero I don't have any error. But I don't have tried function of code...anyway thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Array indexs start at 0, so assuming the URL is something like `/index.php`, the index should be `$parts[1]`

EG:

`$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`

`/index.php/Arg1/Arg2`

```
0: Domain (value before delim - usually null)
/: Deliminator
1: index.php
/: Deliminator
2: Arg1
/: Deliminator
3: Arg2
```

Comment: Assuming the file is at the root of your site, if you var_dump($parts) after using / as a delim, 0 is always empty, 1 is the file, 2+ is everything else.

eg `array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(9) "index.php" }`

Comment: Oh! sorry about that, probably editing before I read your comment

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes:

```
if ($parts[2] == "index.php")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the variable by specifying the array index which is integer. So no need to include quotes to the index and also check with isset() to check whether the array index you are accessing is set or not.

Try with

```
if(isset($parts[2]))
{
if ($parts[2] == "index.php") {
        ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php } 
}
```

Comment: try with the code I have edited in my answer..and let me know if issue is fixed or not..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file name, the best option should be [basename](http://www.php.net/basename%E2%80%8E)

```
$filename = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
if ($filename == 'index.php') {
   // ...
}
```